# CSS - placing line feed after element

Tags: javascript, html, css

The issue I am facing now happens in an automated form generated by JS, which is using controls trimmed in DIVs. The resulting HTML is given here:

```
<div id="E0" style="width:200px;" class="FLD">
    <div style="flex: initial;">Val A：</div>
    <input type="text" style="flex: 1 1 auto;">
</div>
<div id="E1" style="width: 600px;" class="FLD" lf="1">
    <div style="flex: initial;">Val B：</div>
    <input type="text" style="flex: 1 1 auto;">
</div>
<div id="E2" style="width: 400px;" class="FLD">
    <div style="flex: 1 1 auto;">Val C：</div>
    <input style="width:60px; flex:initial;" type="text">
</div>
```

The associated CSS:

```
.FLD{ display:inline-flex; flex-direction:row; }
.FLD[lf]::after{ /* The issue described below*/ }
```

Note that the "inputs" above may be different elements and the above is just "private case".

**The issue:**

- As from the above structure, I expect the DIV "E0" and DIV "E1" to be in the same line, while "E2" in a separate line below (assuming the parent container wide enough, at least).
- The DIVs will appear all inline (because by default I want them to be like this). However, the attribute "lf" if set (can also be set by JS internal property), shall virtually add <br> element after the DIV.
- If I create <br> element after the DIV, it will make a problem if I want to remove the DIV in one command also its "<br>" - as they become 2 separated elements - and as this appears in SPA, I want to have a clean removing function or hidding function to handle that element only, without considering "trailings".
- If I use "display:flex;" instead of "display:inline-flex" for just that one particular element, the situation will become all DIVs in separate lines (not inline element which happen to be the middle one, will cause the previous to be on top and the next below it).
- The last approach I thought to use, is .FLD[lf]::after{ content:'' } selector - but then, my question is comming:

**Is there such possibility in CSS to somehow add line feed (something like "<br>") after DOM element?** I have tried "content", but it seems working on text-string only, so even "\n" is not doing what I want. I believe that is not possible, but maybe I am wrong and there is another way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that what you re asking is possible. But...

You can use float and clear css properties combined:

```
#E0, #E1, #E2{
  float: left;
}
#E2{
  clear: left
}
```

This will arrange your divs in a similar way

Comment: This works, and really works:) Thank you very much:)